# Python: scipy.spsolve crashes without error

Tags: python, opencv, matrix, numpy, scipy

I am not very good with matrices, and for the most part I don't know what I'm doing, as I'm trying to fix someone else's code.

The code in question is `new_vals = scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve(A,b)` where A is a sparse matrix with the following dimensions: (1146880, 1146880), and `b` is (1146880, 1). When python crashes, there are no errors, and I'm pretty sure it's not running out of memory. Some searching suggested that it make be a form of stack overflow, so I tried to formulate a different solution using bicg, but `new_vals,check = scipy.sparse.linalg.bicg(A,b)` doesn't always seem to work.

Are they any ways to get spsolve to work? Or is there another way to do this?

**Edit:** I had previously states that both matrices were the same size, but `b` is (1146880, 1).

Comment: If something doesn't work in Scipy, or something crashes, and you are sure the problem is not in your code, file a bug report here: http://projects.scipy.org/scipy/   Be sure to mention which Scipy version you have (check `scipy.__version__`), and a way for someone else to reproduce the issue. If you are using an old Scipy version, it is a good idea to try with a newer one.

Answer (score 0):

1) What do you mean with "doesn't always seem to work"? Does `bicg` fail with `info!=0`? This wouldn't be surprising, and it can happen because `A` is not invertible. Is it possible that the input, specifically matrix `A`, might be wrong?

2) Does `spsolve` fail in the same cases `bicg` does?

EDIT: in reply to the comment, I wouldn't trust spsolve. This is an example where it fails:

```
import scipy.sparse
import scipy.sparse.linalg

A=scipy.sparse.csc_matrix(linspace(1,15,16).reshape((4,4)))
b=ones((4))
res_spsolve=scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve(A,b)
res_bicg,info=scipy.sparse.linalg.bicg(A,b)


b_bicg = A*res_bicg
b_spsolve = A*res_spsolve
```

you will see that b_spsolve is wrong

Comment: `bicg` fails with `info=-10`. I actually haven't been able to get `bicg` to work at all, even in a case where the matrix is (81920, 81920), when `spsolve` works wonderfully.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't trust spsolve. This is an example where it fails:

Comment: Alright, well in my case I am applying an image transformation using the found `x` from `spsolve`, so by work I mean I get the correct transformation/result.

Is there any other way I can get my result then?

Comment: Well, I find very strange that `bicg` always fails. Can you check if `numpy.linalg.det(A)!=0`, or the matrix is too big? if it is zero or very close to it, I think there might be something wrong with the algorithm itself

Comment: Oh, A is a sparse matrix... (if that changes anything).

Comment: You first have to convert A to an array to calculate the determinant, like `numpy.linalg.det(A.toarray())!=0`. But this will require a lot of memory, of the order of Gbs. The error `info=-10`, means that the biconjugate algorithm fails. You may want to try using `bicgstab` or any other algorithms listed here:http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.linalg.html#solving-linear-problems

Comment: If they don't fail, check in any case that A*x == b afterwards.

Comment: and the result is correct, i.e. the flag `info` is zero and `A*x==b`? How does it compare with the result from `spsolve`?

Comment: The matrix in the example above is singular (determinant ~ 0). The problem is numerically unstable, so it is **expected** that the answer can contain large error. This does not mean that `spsolve` is not to be trusted, just that that the problem is ill-posed. Please make sure you are correct before FUD-ing.

Comment: @AlexNolan, then the algorythm of `spsolve` fails, while `gmres` works, and there is little you can do about it. @pv, if you have a sparse matrix, you usually can't calculate the determinant, and since spsolve doesn't give you any accuracy flag in output, you can't trust the result and you must be cautious. In this case, nothing is expected. `bicg` gives you a flag, you can test that and at least know if that specific algorythm fails.